# How to navigate from a card list using TouchableOpacity in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, touchableopacity

Hi all i'm trying to make a navigation on clicking the `card` (list view) using `TouchableOpacity`.Also i want to pass `cat_id` (response returned from server)along with this(to CourseDetail page) ?Is it possible? Below is my code but i got the error 'can't find variable navigate'.please do help...

**HomeScreen.js**

```
const HomeScreen = ({course}) =>{
    const {name,featured_image,cat_id} = course;

    return(

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>navigate("CourseDetail")}>
    <Card>
     <CardSection>
     <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
         {course.term_id == '28' ? (<View></View>) : (
         <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{name}
         </Text> )}
    </View>
     </CardSection>
    </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator({
CourseDetail:{
    screen: CourseDetail
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following changes. You need to access navigate method through navigation, and before you can do that in a functional component (since there is no longer a this.props) declare your navigation prop too.

Also, you can pass props between screens. Second parameter of navigate function gets passed, and by adding your parameters you can access them in navigated pages in the form: `navigation.state.params.cat_id`. (Note that if that page is a class you need to write `this.props.navigation.state.params.cat_id`)

```
const HomeScreen = ({course, navigation}) =>{
    const {name,featured_image,cat_id} = course;

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CourseDetail", { cat_id })}>
```

Comment: I tried this ,but got this error `undefined is not an object evaluating navigation.navigate`.

Comment: I missed it, you should also add this component as a screen to your StackNavigator. Otherwise it won't get a navigation prop.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you..you mean adding the screen to be navigated?as i do before?

Comment: At the end, you define a StackNavigator. You have added a screen there, which means it is now a route. You need to add this screen to somewhere too, whichever navigator it belongs to.

Comment: So that means i've to add it to `CourseDetail` page also?

Comment: You have to add another entry just like CourseDetail. For example ```Home: { screen: HomeScreen }```

Comment: `HomeScreen` is my current page where i defined this `StackNavigator`. So how do i add that screen itself to `stackNavigator`?

Comment: You have two components defined here. React Native / react-navigation does not work on a file basis, your stack navigator is ```ScheduledApp```. Could you show us how you start the app in HomeScreen? Because if you are opening ```HomeScreen``` as your app, its ```StackNavigator``` is not defined here. If you register ```ScheduledApp``` as your app, you shouldn't see ```HomeScreen``` at all.

Comment: [![This is how my Homescreen look likes][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or5j2.png..I want to navigate to CourseDetail page.No i've not registerd `ScheduledApp`.I've edited my question

Comment: If that is your ```HomeScreen``` why aren't you declaring ```CourseDetail``` where you declared ```HomeScreen```? You just need to navigate you do not need a new ```StackNavigator```.

Comment: `HomeScreen` is the main page (shown in the above screenshot).Also i've pasted the code for it above in my question.`CourseDetail` is the 2nd page which i want to navigate when i click on the `card list` (screenshot).So do i need to define `stacknavigator` in my 2nd page also?Please help i am confused

Comment: Your updated code doesn't show. If ```HomeScreen``` is your main screen, I assume that means you register that as your app. You should register a ```StackNavigator``` as your app. Within that ```StackNavigator``` declare both pages and after that it should work like a charm. If you have further issues lets move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163092/discussion-between-neethu-m-and-h-tugkan-kibar).